# Sqoop error for java.io.charconversionException which is non UTF-8 charactor

Tags: hadoop, exception, sqoop

I was trying to sqoop import the data from db2.ibm but stuck up with the error which is

```
java.io.charconversionException: SQL exception in nextKeyValue 
And caused by [jcc][t4][1065]..... Caught java.io.CharConversionException ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
```

I've tried

```
sqoop import --driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver --connect jdbc:db2://host:port/db --verbose table.views_data -m 1 --target-dir /tmp/data
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a bad character in the table you're loading per this IBM article: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684365

If you want to try and workaround it without fixing the data as suggested above, the [DataDirect DB2 JDBC driver](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/ibm-db2) has a property to override code page with one of [these values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html): http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/jdbc/alljdbc/help.html#page/jdbcconnect%2Fcodepageoverride.html%23

Comment: Hey Thanks for the link, the actual issue is from the source table having Chinese Characters which the sqoop import throws char exception and it is UTF-8 char, the source table was reloaded to modify that change and I was able to import the data to Hdfs. It worked